# Apple WatchKit with Xcode 6.3.2 - not able to create a project?

Tags: xcode6, watchkit

I'm using Xcode 6.3.2 (6D2105) but when i try to create a project for or with the watchKit there is no template for watchKit or the apple watch. What do i need to download or install in addition to create project for the apple watch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't start a new WatchKit project, per se. WatchKit apps are simply another target bundled into your iOS app.

After you have created your iOS project, you can go to File > New Target and select WatchKit app.

Comment: ah, thats why...ok thank you. i created a project = ok, then i added a new target and yep there it is!!! its a little unusual for me but, lets see what comes out.